# remote api for java

Tags: java, windows-mobile

Is there a java api similar to [RAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920177.aspx)? I want to be able to access files on the windows mobile device using a java desktop program.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use RAPI itself, and access it from Java using JNI or a wrapper like [Swig](http://www.swig.org/)

Comment: @finnw: sure. There are lots of native libs access wrappers, I just posted this one as an example, but you can choose the one you rather (or the one which best fits the requirements).

Answer (score -1):

We were also looking for a similar API in Java but unfortunately none is available. I wrote my own RAPI wrapper using JNI and used that in my program.

The main problem with JNI is that any un-handled exceptions/faults cause the calling Java program to shutdown as well. Do keep that in mind when writing your wrapper. There are different approaches to safe guard these, the simplest and common approach is to write a standalone program written in .Net/C++ that communicates with the RAPI and your Java program communicates with that program using pipes/files etc. this way you also don't have to write a JNI wrapper :-)